# Java newbie (linux,Terminal) level is 1.5

Tags: java

I am trying to Build a JAR File of Interface Classes
I am using Linux and working throughout the terminal
I keep getting this error

Syntax error , type parameters are only available if source level is 1.5

I searched many sites and most solutions were about java on windows
to change properties

but how can I do that on linux ?
how can I solve this issue please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your javac command line, add "-source 1.5".

It should read:

> javac -source 1.5 ...

See also:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/javac.html

Comment: This is not going to work if DarkElieDraven is using a Java version that is older than Java 5.

Comment: thank you so much man .. I nearly spent 2 hours searching for solution ... thanx alot :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check your java version in your command line using:

> java -version

and be sure that you are using a version 1.5 or more. And check that in your **build.xml** you are not saying that your java version is less than 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

It can be fixed in same way as on windows.

If you are using Ant to build your project just add or change source attribute of the javac task, see [Ant javac documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html). It should be looks like:

```
<javac ...

         source="1.5"/>
```

If you are using command line tool to perform compilation ensure that you are using the correct version of the java compiler (see output of the `java -version`, you can't compile java15 java source classes using 1.4 or lower java compiler) and add `-source 1.5` parameter to compile command. It should be like:

```
javac -source 1.5 ...java classes...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have Java source code that uses generics, which is a feature added to Java 5, but you are most likely using a Java compiler from an older version (Java 1.4 or older). You can check which version of Java you are running with a command like `java -version`.

Install a newer JDK. What the best way is to do that depends on your Linux distribution.